# iOS AUSampler Play midi note continuously

Tags: ios, core-audio, coremidi

I am trying to play midi notes with help of sf2 files using `AUSampler audio unit`. I was able to start and stop note fine using `MusicDeviceMIDIEvent` function as below.

```
noteCommand =   kMIDIMessage_NoteOn << 4 | 0;
MusicDeviceMIDIEvent (samplerUnit, noteCommand, note, velocity, 0);
```

The note stops after sometime even if I don't call `MusicDeviceMIDIEvent` function with NoteOff message.

Is there any way to get this note play on until I call the `MusicDeviceMIDIEvent` with NoteOff? or should the sf2 file be created in a different way so that it contains different sound files for note attack, note sustain etc and the `AUSampler` unit automatically takes care of playing the sustain sound till NoteOff is called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set it up in your sf2 file or AUPreset, if you use those. For AUPresets, here's Apple's [Tech Note TN2283](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2283/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011217-CH1-CREATING_A_CUSTOM_PRESET_FROM_INDIVIDUAL_AUDIO_FILES):

> Looping is specified using a Region List property
>   (kAudioFilePropertyRegionList) describing a segment of looped audio
>   data and can be set with the AudioFileSetProperty API.

Here's a [long tutorial](http://ericshowto.weebly.com/garagebands-hidden-ausampler.html) on using Garageband to set up a looping AUSampler. AU Lab also can generate AUPresets.

For sf2, a [youtube](http://www.swamiproject.org/) video showing how to set up looping. Not clear what software he is using. If you are feeling adventurous, you could try building the open source [Swami](http://www.swamiproject.org/) for OSX

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom! I will try to get the sf2 specify looping region and see.

Comment: I have found this "kAUGroupParameterID_Sustain" parameter under properties for sampler units.. can this be of any help?

Comment: I have tried setting this parameter.. AudioUnitSetParameter(auSamplerUnit,
          kAUGroupParameterID_Volume,
          kAudioUnitScope_Global,
          0,
          someValue,
          0)  but this always fails with "-10878" error.

Comment: Haven't done that myself - but that error code is `kAudioUnitErr_InvalidParameter` - (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) - so check the parameters you are passing - not enough? too many? wrong type? etc.